# MySQL check if field is empty and then run query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set an if/else statement that will check if a field is empty and then run an insert query and if it is not empty it will run an update query. I know that both queries are correct if I run them separately they will work, however when I put them in my if/else statement it will only do the update query when I've manually entered in a row in the mysql. Basically I can run the update query but not the insert.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['htype'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO fetss.ocs_extended(ocsID, hwTYPE)
        VALUES('" .(int)$_POST['id'] ."', '". $db->quote($_REQUEST['changeTypeID']) ."')";
} else
{
    $sql = "UPDATE fetss.ocs_extended SET hwTYPE = '".$db->quote($_REQUEST['changeTypeID'])."' WHERE ocsID IN (".join(",",$checkedHW).")";
}
    $db->query($sql);
```

html code (I'm using smarty so I have the value set to the hardware type and I am displaying the value in the td tags:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="htype" value="{$systems[s].hwtype}">{$systems[s].hwtype}  </td>
```

I also tried using INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE etc, but it didn't work so I thought I'd try a simple if/else statement

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

edit this was my duplicate key query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO fetss.ocs_extended(ocsID, hwTYPE)
                                        VALUES('" .(int)$_POST['id'] ."', '". $db->quote($_REQUEST['changeTypeID']) ."')
                                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hwTYPE = '".$db->quote($_REQUEST['changeTypeID'])."'";
```

Comment: I am not sure why do you want to insert. If a particular column is empty in a row or has some data, you need to update the row and to have the desired value in that column.

Comment: The purpose of the insert is because I have a new table that was added and needs to be joined to my existing hardware table. The rows are not yet inserted into this new table yet, so I created a few test rows and I am able to update those rows with my query

Answer (score 0):

The update will fail if there's no row in the database...

Go back to ON DUPLICATE KEY.  It's what you're after.

Comment: This was my on duplicate key code: trying to figure out formatting one sec
    

    $sql = "INSERT INTO fetss.ocs_extended(ocsID, hwTYPE)
              VALUES('" .(int)$_POST['id'] ."', '". $db->quote($_REQUEST['changeTypeID']) ."')
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hwTYPE = '".$db->quote($_REQUEST['changeTypeID'])."'";

Comment: Sure I think this is what it looks if its simplified: INSERT INTO table(id, type) VALUES(id, type) on duplicate key update type="type";

Comment: Also I don't know if if makes a difference, but my table consists of 5 fields, id, type, location, text1,text2

Comment: I can get an example working with just the two columns you've mentioned so far if there's a `PRIMARY KEY` on _id_: `insert into ocs_extended (id, type) values (1, "Pear") on duplicate key update type = "Pear";`

Comment: Since your table has more columns than you originally described, note that `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is only going to fire when the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is being violated, so make sure it's setup the way you would expect and that you are, in fact, inserting a duplicate.

Comment: After testing everything again, my insert query actually does not work. User error fail. thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make use of MySQL's [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) syntax:

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO fetss.ocs_extended (ocsID, hwTYPE) VALUES ('" .(int)$_POST['id'] ."', '". $db->quote($_REQUEST['changeTypeID']) ."')";
```

It works just like an `INSERT INTO` statement, however, if the primary-key exists that you're "replacing into", it will delete the existing and insert the new. This can save you your if/else statement and take care of it in a single statement.

I'm not certain what is in your `$checkedHW` variable, in the event that `$_REQUEST['htype']` is set, so this may or may not suit your needs. Speaking of which, you check if `$_REQUEST['htype']` is set but never use it in the code you have shown - is this intended?